# is HTTP server header response ignored?

Tags: java, html, http

I make very simple HTTP server in Java. The response sent to the browser is

```
HTTP 1.1 200 OK
Server: OneFile 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 202
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>My website</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Document </H1>
</BODY></HTML>
```

mozilla firefox displays it as text/plain although it should be text/html Why?
I suspect the Setup info is ignored...is it any difference for browser if I make connection on port 8080?
Thanks for any help

Comment: What part of this is Firefox displaying in plain text? Does it include these headers or only the HTML?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HTTP/1.1`? Also, I don't see any trace of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the body.

Comment: The status should be HTTP/1.1
What kind of line endings are you using?

Comment: Redundant, did not see axtavt comment.

Comment: @BoltClock: My testing indicates it shows the full reponse, headers included.

Comment: Either use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` or `Content-Length`, but not both together.

Comment: @ibid: I just put everything together now (and upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 4):

The browser will honor your headers.  Unfortunately, your response is malformed for several reasons:

- the response should start `HTTP/1.1`, not `HTTP 1.1`
- you specify `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, but your response does not follow the `chunked` format.

It appears that Firefox, quite sensibly, refuses to interpret such malformed response and just shows it unchanged.